# How can I set a variable that was defined in another class with the onClick method in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to re-define a variable from another class when I press a button. I have tried all that i can think of, and none of the code works. The variable will output a different line based on which number the variable is.

Comment: Share the code and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pls.

Comment: Share the code with us. You can easily so this as long as your button has a reference to the class you want to alter.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your variable in MainActivity like:

```
static int youVariable = 0;
```

then, you can access it into another activity with:

```
MainActivity.yourVariable = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a couple of issues, that I will try to guide along:

`I am trying to re-define a variable from another class`

Classes should not have attributes that are specific for an Object.

Example: `Car` is a class for cars, `Car` has color, tires, and doors...a `Car` can accelerate, turn, and crash...

In your `Road` Object, you create cars in it, and make them move... you should not tell `Car` Class to move. Just the `Car` Objects:

```
Car bigCar = new Car();
bigCar.accelerate();
```

instead of

```
Car.accelerate();
```

Now, if you want to get data from `Car` that makes sence from all car perspectives, but not an specific one (such as the movements a car is allowed)

Then you can have:

```
public Class Car(){
   private String color, size, tireType;

   public static String getAllowedMoves(){return "Accell, Turn, Crash"};

   public void accelerate(){};
   public void turn(){};
   public void crash(){};
}
```

And in your code:

```
Log.v("YOUR TAG", "A Car can: " + Car.getAllowedMoves();
```